# Operator += not compatible with types String memory and bytes memory?

Tags: solidity, string

How can I add, string(b[i] to number & alpha variable?

```
        bytes memory number;
        bytes memory alpha;

        function getNumAndAlpha() public pure external returns( bytes n, bytes a){

        string memory str = "1jfjw2j34jcnsj512jdn3";

        bytes memory b = bytes(str);

        for(uint i=0; i< b.length; i++){

            if (b[i] == "0"  b[i] == "1"b[i] == "2"  b[i] == "2"  b[i] == "4" || b[i] == "5") {

                number += string(b[i]\n);

            } else {

                alpha += string(b[i]\n);
            }
        }
            return (number, alpha)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version of your code that concentrates bytes and separates Numbers from Letters (What I asssume you wanted to do here).

Hope it helps.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract Contract {

 

    function getNumAndAlpha() public pure returns( string memory Number, string memory Alpha){

    bytes memory number;
    bytes memory alpha;
    string memory str = "1jfjw2j34jcnsj512jdn3";

    bytes memory b = bytes(str);

    for(uint i=0; i < b.length; i++){

        if (b[i] == "0" ||  b[i] == "1" || b[i] == "2" || b[i] == "3" || b[i] == "4" || b[i] == "5") {

            number = (abi.encodePacked(number,b[i]));

        } else {

           alpha = (abi.encodePacked(alpha,b[i]));
        }
    }

          return (string(number), string(alpha));

    }


}
```

Comment: function concatenate(string memory s1, string memory d1 public pure returns (string memory value) {
        // for(uint i = 0; i < user.)
        string memory b;
        b = (abi.encodePacked(b,s1));
        b = (abi.encodePacked(b,d1));
        return (string(b);
        // return b;
    }



When I'm using the same approach with this code, then it's not working?
Can you look and let me know, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Could you please post this in a separate question that way I can have a better overview of it, and someone who might have a similar issue might be able to find it.